# supabaseUrl is required sveltekit

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit, supabase

I'm having this problem for quite a while and want to solve this:
According to supbase [documentation](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/with-sveltekit) you create a **.env** file

```
VITE_SUPABASE_URL="YOUR_SUPABASE_URL"
VITE_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY="YOUR_SUPABASE_KEY"
```

then you call them in supabaseClient.js:

```
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'

const supabaseUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_SUPABASE_URL
const supabaseAnonKey = import.meta.env.VITE_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY

export const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseAnonKey)
```

However this doesnt work,I get **supabaseUrl is required.** and the env variables are not getting exported.

Does anyone know why and how to solve it?

Do I need to install any additional lib?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SvelteKit recently added new stores to import env variables, like [`$env/static/private`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$env-static-private). To use:

```
# .env file
PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL="YOUR_SUPABASE_URL"
PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY="YOUR_SUPABASE_KEY"
```

```
// supabaseClient.js

import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'   
import {PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL, PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY} from '$env/static/public'

export const supabase = createClient(PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL, PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY)
```

This should work, however note your secrets are being exposed in publicly accessible JS files (thus the `PUBLIC_` prefix). So it is better to only access supabase from SvelteKit endpoints (which that tutorial doesn't do.) To do this, you should use the `$env/static/private` store and env variables *without* the `PUBLIC_` prefix. (You will also have to refactor your supabase code to be in a Svelte endpoint, not a Svelte page/component.)

*Warning:* The SvelteKit API is in flux, and the final v1.0 way to do this may be quite different. The latest SvelteKit already introduced major breaking changes:

- https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/discussions/5748
- https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/discussions/5875

---

I have used the old `VITE_SUPABASE_URL` + `import.meta.env.VITE_SUPABASE_URL` method before, so it should work. I'm not sure if SvelteKit disabled this method as they introduced the new env variable stores.

**update:** If you would like to continue using the old `import.meta.env.VITE_SUPABASE_URL` method, it may be possible by setting [`envPrefix`](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#envprefix) in your [vite.config.js](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/project-structure#project-files-vite-config-js) (Source: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#env)

Comment: the PUBLIC_ is not something to be taken in consideration, although it is a solution to importing variables. I just tested them and again something might be wrong from my side. If I go to my .env file I do have `VITE_SUPABASE_URL & VITE_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY&PRIVATE_SUPABASE_URL` and I call them at supabaseclient.js like this `import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'
import { PRIVATE_SUPABASE_URL } from '$env/static/private';
const supabaseUr = env.PRIVATE_SUPABASE_URL
console.log(supabaseUr)` **env is not defined** Please let me know what I doing wrong

Comment: @equi: Your env variables names need to match. Right now, you're using `VITE_SUPABASE_URL` in your .env file but trying to import `PRIVATE_SUPABASE_URL`. Also `env.PRIVATE_SUPABASE_URL` is for dynamic env variables. For static env variables you import them directly like my example in my answer. I suggest you first get my PUBLIC_ example working, then modify the working project to use private env variables.

Comment: so I figured out where the problem is....the .env should not be inside src/ directory but in your main project directory...this fixes everything.thank you for your help.please add one more line to your answer